# CherryPy: Exception handling help needed

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, cherrypy

I have a html.app that ask asynchronously for its JSON data model from CherryPy Backend. The size of JSON data is somewhat large 1.74 MB. It takes about 1 sec to load and render the data. The app works fine while standalone. However when I attach it to Apache web server via mod_wsgi I immediately started noticing issues.

When html page is being refreshed before the data connection is closed mod_wsgi triggers its infamous

```
  mod_wsgi (pid=917): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/myapp_path/WebApp.py'
  IOError: failed to write data, referer: https://domain/etc/padmin/
  ENGINE Started monitor thread 'Session cleanup'.
  ENGINE Started monitor thread 'Session cleanup'.
```

I understand Apache closes the data connection before WSGI has opportunity to pump the data in its entirety to a client.  It's not a big deal but it raises some sort of internal exception which I can't really trap or don't know how to. The default behavior of CherryPy is to reset session if unhanded exception occurs.  I need to change CherryPy's behavior so it wouldn't reset active session when client chooses not to wait long for data completion. I would prefer to trap and suppress mod_wsgi exception solution, but if not possible I'd opt to prevent 'Session cleanup' action if unhanded exception occurs. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**
I traced my issue to improperly configured session storage type. It was supposed to be `file` but due to illegal value, it turned to be a default `ram` type. The issue was resolved.

Comment: It is not Apache closing the connection, but the HTTP client that is doing so.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I am thinking of modifying your code to ignore this event. I just don't see how ajax or streaming apps can work with CherryPy with that.

Comment: In modifying it you would be violating the WSGI specification. Unless you are using the WSGI write() callback, which is unlikely, you should never see this exception in your WSGI application so I think you must be misinterpreting something.

Comment: The only way that CherryPy would even know it occurred is if it was streaming data in blocks and saw the close() on the returned iterable called prior to all blocks having being yielded. I would be surprised if it went to such lengths.

Comment: Please update the question with simple tests -- command line (e.g. curl) test against plain cherrypy, and same against Apache. How long does your python bit take to serve the response? Do you always get the error or only sometimes? Do you get same request (cherrypy) and response (curl) headers?

Comment: I am not entirely sure how curl will execute JQuery async calls to fetch the data, after the DOM is assembled. Using curl doesn't make any sense to me. Plain CherryPy doesn't have any issues at all. Th error is always reproducible. I am not sure I understand the last question.

Comment: I suggest you answer your question with "I traced my issue to improperly configured session storage type. It was supposed to be file but due to illegal value, it turned to be a default ram type. The issue was resolved." and then accept that question.

Answer (score 1):

I program python, so I am not sure how html handles exceptions, but there should by a "try and catch" system for it. This means that you can try to execute some code, and if it fails you can do something else. You can also specify which error will trigger the second piece of code. Here is a python example:

```
try:
    #do something here
except IOError, e:
    #in the event of an IO error, do this, e is a variable you can choose to pass in that gives details about the error
except SystemExit:
    #another python exception
finally:
    #it is possible that html also supports a finally. Basically, no matter if it executes the try or one of the exception handlers, it will finish by doing this no matter what.
```

Comment: I appreciate your feedback. Please look to the update portion of my question.

Comment: finally support is a function of Python version, has nothing to do with html.

Comment: Yet html definitely has exception handling.